# "-bash: [git: command not found " in bash script on mac

Tags: bash, git, macos

I am creating a bash script to do git commands. In one function, I use if statement on git status:

```
if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
    echo "has change"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

Then it gives this error:

```
-bash: [git: command not found
```

git works just fine in command line. It also works fine in my other functions without the if statement.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the statement that causes the error? More likely, you have a statement that has no space between `[` and `git`, e.g. `if [git status]; then true; fi`

Answer (score 3):

> -bash: [git: command not found

This error indicates that you don't have space between your <kbd>[</kbd> and the rest of your command as you can see in the screenshot below (no space on line #1)

[image]